# Response object along with http status code

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

I want to return http status code along with response object.   If i just return response object in failure scenario the status is getting returned as 200.  But i want to send the status that is returned by the service (eg: 403) along with the response object.  But below piece of code is just returning message along with the status.  I want response object in this case orderdetails object which has failure reasons and other fields.  any help how to pass object back to client?

```
@Component
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private OrderService service;

    public OrderDetails createOrder(final OrderDetails orderVO) {
        try {
            OrderDetails orderVO = service.createOrder() // service call
        } catch(OrderException e) {
            OrderDetails orderVO = e.getOrderDetails(); // even in exception cases backend liberary sends same object with error messages        
            ServiceException exception = new ServiceException(e.getStatus(), e.getMessage());
            exception.setOrderDetails(orderVO);
            throw exception;
        }
        return orderVO; 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Comment: To give further details on JB Nizet link, look for ResponseEntity or exception handling metodologies (such as the ExceptionHandler annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `@ControllerAdvice` and add your error handling logic there.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SampleControllerAdvice {

     @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
     public ResponseEntity<YourResponse> handleServiceException(ServiceException e) {
         // YourResponse could be any serializable type (including ServiceException)
         YourResponse body = ...
         // Set the desired HTTP response headers
         HttpHeaders responseHeaders = ...
         // Set the desired HTTP response status
         HttpStatus status = ...
         return new ResponseEntity<YourResponse>(body, headers, status);
     }

}
```

If `ServiceException` gets throws the handler method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the OrderDetails in the OrderException is null...
So with *exception.setOrderDetails(orderVO);* you put null in the Exception!!!